# ES6 - How to return a nested object property value by filtering in Java Script

Tags: javascript, filter, ecmascript-6

#### Finding the nested object property value based on  filter

Please suggest the best ways of identifying getting name for the given item id 03.

```
const product = products.find(product => product.items.some(item => item.id === '03'));
```

Gives the product but will have to loop again to find the name ?

```
    const products = [
      {
        id: 'p1',
    items: [
      {
        id: 01,
        name: 'iphone'
      },
      {
        id: 02,
        name: 'samsung'
      },
      {
        id: 03,
        name: 'oneplus'
      }
    ]
      },
      {
    id: 'p2',
    items: [
      {
        id: 04,
        name: 'nokia'
      },
      {
        id: 05,
        name: 'nexus'
      },
      {
        id: 06,
        name: 'phone3'
      }
    ]
  }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do like:

```
const product = products
  .reduce((acc, product) => {
    return [...acc, ...product.items];
  }, [])
  .find(item => item.id === "03");
const productName = product && product.name;
console.log(productName); // oneplus
```

Comment: thanks Arup
the last statement should be
it should  const productName = product && product.name;

Comment: @Joe Yes. I had lost the internet, so I was not able to correct my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be concerned about performance, and it looks like there will only be one matching id - the classic `for` loop is best suited for this task.

```
let matchingItem;
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
    const product = products[i];
    matchingItem = product.items.find(item => item.id === "03");
    if (matchingItem) {
        break;
    }
}
```

---

It's not very fancy, but the ability to stop execution as soon as a match is found makes it the best choice.

Comment: yes agree but not many likes old fashion for-loop with break statements added
as newer version of ES6 functions break out when match found